# Check if the result of Count equals zero Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a need to perform MINUS operation between two similar tables, count the resulting rows and check if the count is equal to zero all in a SQL statement.

I have done the following but i am not sure about how to compare it to zero.

```
select count(*) from(select * from table1 MINUS SELECT * FROM table2)
```

Comment: What should happen if the count is equal to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with t_minus as
  2    (select deptno from emp
  3     minus
  4     select deptno from dept
  5    )
  6  select case when count(*) = 0 then 'it is zero'
  7              else 'it is not zero'
  8         end result
  9  from t_minus;

RESULT
--------------
it is zero
```

---

```
SQL> with t_minus as
  2    (select empno from emp
  3     minus
  4     select deptno from dept
  5    )
  6  select case when count(*) = 0 then 'it is zero'
  7              else 'it is not zero'
  8         end result
  9  from t_minus;

RESULT
--------------
it is not zero

SQL>
```